# Searching on the properties of objects in an array

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have an NSArray of objects with properties such as firstName, lastName, clientID etc. and i would like to perform a search on the array based on a search keyword. This keyword must be checked against the first name and the last name properties and return a subset of the original array that contains only those objects whose first/last name contain the search term. Is there any efficient/fast way to do this?

Comment: Im not trying to do a full name match. If my search term is for ex. "fr" the results could be like Franz Smith, Frank Jones, John Frappe

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think your looking for [`-indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/indexesOfObjectsPassingTest%3a)

```
NSIndexSet *indexSet = [array indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    MyObject *myObject = (MyObject *)obj;
    return [myObject.firstName isEqualToString:@"Bob"];
}];
```

This returns an index set of all the objects in the array with the first name of "Bob".

Answer (score 11):

As a second thought, I think [`-filteredArrayUsingPredicate:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BAJJDBEB) might be better for you.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K = %@", @"firstName", @"Bob"];
NSArray *filteredArray = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

This returns a sub-array of objects from the array that have the first name of "Bob".

Answer (score 0):

Another approach returning a new array containing only matching objects:

```
-(NSArray *)matchingClientsFromArray:(NSArray *)objects withFirstName:(NSString *)firstName andLastName:(NSString *)lastName{
    NSMutableArray *objectArray = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (Client *client in objectArray){
        if ([client.firstName isEqualToString:firstName] &&
              [client.lastName isEqualToString:lastName]) {
            [objectArray addObject:client];
        }
    }
    return [objectArray copy];
}
```